# Filter with Pagination using Angular

Tags: angular, html, pagination

I am creating a dashboard using angular where I have a table with search bar and pagination.Without entering value in filter bar everything is working fine but as soon a i am entering value .Filtering is happening on per page of pagination.

Example- Total records- 100
         Records Per Page =10
 if first page contains 3 people and 2nd page contains 7 people with name SAM then it will show 3 people in first page and 7 in 2nd.

below is my code.

```
<table>
     <tr ng-repeat="show in showdata | filter:namefilter.entity | pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize "* >
         <td> {{show.name}}</td>
         <td> {{show.age}}</td>
     </tr>
</table>
 <div class="pagination pagination-centered" ng-show="showdata.length">
     <ul  class="pagination-controle pagination">
          <li>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-disabled="curPage == 0" ng-click="curPage=curPage-1"> &lt;PREV</button>
          </li>
          <li>
             <span>Page {{curPage + 1}} of {{ numberOfPages() }}</span>
          </li>
          <li>
             <button type="button"   class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="curPage >= showdata.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="curPage = curPage+1">NEXT&gt; </button>
           </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Angular code

```
$scope.curPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 13;
$scope.numberOfPages = function()
{
    return Math.ceil($scope.showdata.length / $scope.pageSize);
};

Report.filter('pagination', function()
{
    return function(input, start)
    {
        start = +start;
        return input.slice(start);
    };
});

Report.filter('search', function() {
    return function(items, keyword) {
        /* if no keyword is entered, just display all the items*/
        if (!keyword) {
           return items;
        }
        else {
            var newItems = [];
            var keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();
            /*create new set of items where 'keyword' exists in object data*/
            for (var i in items) {
                if (i.entity.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1 )
                 { newItems.push(i); }
                              }
                            }
             }
             $scope.numberOfPages = function()
          {


        return newItems;
     });
```

I want after filter pages number also reset.
Any lead will be helpful.

Comment: I don't think ng-repeat exists in Agular2+, only in AngularJS. You will need to use *ngFor instead.

Answer (score 0):

I did pagination on an Ionic mobile app - that uses Angular under the covers...

In my version, I passed a page number and number of records per page as params on the RESTFIL web service. I also returned the keys of next record, and prior to make it easy for webservice to go to next/prior page.
So each time I deal with a fresh set per page.
All the heavy lifting, and filtering options were done server-side so as to not send back a huge payload and filter client side.